# Can I add tenant wise policy in wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am using wso2 api manager ,I would like to add policies for the tenant like if a tenant has 2 users and I need to enable that tenant to use one API  upto 5 request only and another API unlimited when tenant is selected a specifc policy named "free" and also need to enable unlimited request to both APIs when tenant selected  another policy eg:"Standard"
Also In this case i need to count the requests by both users in this single quota.
Means that if 1st user from  the tenant sent 3 request and 2nd user of same tenant sent 2 request , i need to stop  any more request from any users under this tenant ,Is it possible to do so ?

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 1):

Defining a [custom policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68465848/6045187) for a tenant using the admin console will solve your use case. Building a siddhi query precisely will give a wide range of customizability to your implementation. Also, check out this [link](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/rate-limiting/introducing-throttling-use-cases/) where you can learn more about throttling related use cases.

Comment: How can I add custom policy to an API 
I need to create multiple custom policy and make it available for user to pick while subscribing to API
Is it possible?

Comment: custom policies are meant to be attached per API. What you mean is accomplished using subscription policies, which also can be defined via the admin portal

Answer (score 0):

You can add different policies at different levels and these are applied at tenant wise.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/rate-limiting/adding-new-throttling-policies/#adding-a-new-advanced-throttling-policy

This is how throttling applies in API Manager.

[image]

Also you can define custom policies where you can apply globally or tenant wise. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/rate-limiting/advanced-topics/custom-throttling/#custom-throttling

Comment: Can you provide some example on how I can limit number of requests from any user in a tenant.